# Convert UTC DateTime to DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetimeoffset

I need to convert `UTC` date strings to `DateTimeOffsets`.

**This must work with a timezone which differs from the computers timezone.**
E.g. current computer timezone is +02:00, but I want to create a DateTimeOffset with offset -4:00.

I already read lot of questions here on stackoverflow, but none of them solved my problem.

That is what I need to do:

**Input:** "2012-11-20T00:00:00Z"

**Output:** DateTimeOffset with:

- UtcDateTime of **2012-11-20 00:00**
- the correct Utc offset for the defined timezone (01:00 in this example)
- LocalDateTime: **2012-11-20 01:00**  (= UtcDateTime + Offset)

Of course daylight saving must be taken into account.

**edit**:
To make things even clearer, please try to complete the following code snippet:

```
DateTimeOffset result;
const string dateString = "2012-11-20T00:00:00Z";
var timezone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time"); //this timezone has an offset of +01:00:00 on this date

//do conversion here

Assert.AreEqual(result.Offset, new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));  //the correct utc offset, in this case +01:00:00
Assert.AreEqual(result.UtcDateTime, new DateTime(2012, 11, 20, 0, 0, 0)); //equals the original date
Assert.AreEqual(result.LocalDateTime, new DateTime(2012, 11, 20, 1, 0, 0));
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is the solution you are looking for:

```
const string dateString = "2012-11-20T00:00:00Z";
TimeZoneInfo timezone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time"); //this timezone has an offset of +01:00:00 on this date

DateTimeOffset utc = DateTimeOffset.Parse(dateString);
DateTimeOffset result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utc, timezone);
        
Assert.AreEqual(result.Offset, new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));  //the correct utc offset, in this case +01:00:00
Assert.AreEqual(result.UtcDateTime, new DateTime(2012, 11, 20, 0, 0, 0)); //equals the original date
Assert.AreEqual(result.DateTime, new DateTime(2012, 11, 20, 1, 0, 0));
```

Note that you were incorrectly testing the `.LocalDateTime` property - which is *always* going to convert the result to the local time zone of the computer.  You simply need the `.DateTime` property instead.

Comment: @BojidarStanchev - Nothing wrong with `var`, but I agree that examples are clearer with explicit typing.  I edited the answer accordingly. Keep in mind the original answer was posted 8 years ago.  Also, you can always propose an edit instead of complaining.

Comment: the complaining worked just as well and was way less effort

Answer (score 8):

Is this what you want:

```
[Test]
public void ParseUtcDateTimeTest()
{
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse("2012-11-20T00:00:00Z");
    Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2012, 11, 20, 01, 00, 00), dateTime);
    DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset = new DateTimeOffset(dateTime);
    Assert.AreEqual(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0, 0), dateTimeOffset.Offset);
}
```

- Note that my asserts are valid in Sweden (CET)
- There are a couple of overloads on [`DateTime.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fw7727c.aspx)

Is this useful for your conversion:

```
[Test]
public void ConvertTimeTest()
{
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse("2012-11-20T00:00:00Z");
    TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard     Time");
    DateTime convertedTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateTime, cstZone);
    Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2012, 11, 19, 18, 00, 00), convertedTime);
    TimeSpan baseUtcOffset = cstZone.BaseUtcOffset;
    Assert.AreEqual(new TimeSpan(0, -6, 0, 0), baseUtcOffset);
}
```

Comment: This won't work if I want to use another timezone than the current timezone.

Comment: @Fabian Updated my answer, hope it helps

Comment: I'm not sure how this can help me. Converting the DateTime is nice and all, but how do I get a DateTimeOffset?

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static DateTimeOffset ToDatetimeOffsetFromUtc(this DateTime date) =>
        new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.SpecifyKind(date, DateTimeKind.Utc));
```

try this extension

Answer (score -1):

```cs
const String dateString = "2012-11-20T00:00:00Z"; 
var offsetDate = DateTimeOffset.Parse(dateString); 
var offsetDate2 = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
```

Output is

```
offsetDate  {20-11-2012 0:00:00 +00:00}    System.DateTimeOffset
offsetDate2 {20-11-2012 1:00:00}           System.DateTime
```

Comment: This won't work if I want to use another timezone than the current timezone.

Comment: Add the second parameter, the cultureinfo. here is a list http://sharpertutorials.com/list-of-culture-codes/. example : var fmt = new CultureInfo("en-AU").DateTimeFormat;

Comment: I tried this, but no matter which CultureInfo I use the DateTimeOffset always has an offset of 00:00:00, which is not what I want!