# Convert date stored as DT_STR to DT_DBDATETIMEOFFSET

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, ssis, etl

I have Delimited text file where I'm loading into Database table
How can I load DT_STR col to DT_DBDATE ,DT_STR to DT_DATETIME.

[image]

In Text file

```
COL1 : Predicted delivery date : DT_STR
COL2  : ScanDateTime : DT_STR
```

[image]

In Destination Table :

```
COL1 : Predicted delivery date : DATE  (DataType)
COL2  : ScanDateTime : DATETIME
```

and I need to load data in this below format

```
Switchoffset (Substring(ScanDateTime , 1, 22)+':'+Substring(ScanDateTime , 23, 24),'-05:00')
```

I have trying to load this data into destination table using Derived column :

I gave this expression for

*COL 1:*

```
(DT_DBDATE)LEFT([Predicted Delivery Date],10)
```

*COL 2:*

```
(DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING([ScanDateTime ],1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([ScanDateTime ],5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([ScanDateTime ],7,2),'-05:00')
```

But both are giving error :

> [Derived Column [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2AhT.png)] Error: An error occurred while attempting to
>   perform a type cast. [Derived Column [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2AhT.png)] Error: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Derived Column" failed
>   because error code 0xC0049064 occurred, and the error row disposition
>   on "Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column Output].Columns[Predicted]"
>   specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object
>   of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before
>   this with more information about the failure.

For Col1, how I need to handle Null values and Load the data into Destination table which is Date Format?

For Col2, how I can write an expression for `Switchoffset` (exp) - 5hrs for that date time column and load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Predicted delivery date Null handling

You can add a derived column with the following expression:

```
(ISNULL([Predicted delivery date]) || [Predicted delivery date] == "") ? 
NULL(DT_DATE) : 
(DT_DATE)[Predicted delivery date]
```

### ScanDateTime offset handling

You can solve the problem by adding a Script Component trasnformation, select ScanDateTime as input column and add a new column of type `DT_DBDATETIMEOFFSET` named `outDate`, inside the script use the following code:

```cs
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row) 
{ 
    if (!Row.ScanDateTime_IsNull && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.ScanDateTime)){

        DateTime dtDate = DateTime.Parse(Row.ScanDateTime);
        dtDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dtDate, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
        DateTimeOffset offDate = new DateTimeOffset(dtDate,
                               TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time").GetUtcOffset(dtDate));

        Row.outDate = offDate;

    }else{

        Row.outDate_IsNull = True;

    }
}
```

#### References

- [Convert UTC DateTime to DateTimeOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933654/convert-utc-datetime-to-datetimeoffset)
- [Converting between DateTime and DateTimeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-datetime-and-offset)

Comment: I have used the DT_DBDATETIMEOFFSET named outdate in Derived column using as output in script component

Comment: How I need to get the outdate column into the script component

Comment: @mohan111 concerning ScanDateTime, forget about derived column just add a Script component, double click on it, in the `Inputs and Outputs`, expand the `Output 0` and click the `Output Columns`. Press `Add Column` to add an output column

Comment: @mohan111 check the following link forca step by step tutorial https://www.sqlshack.com/ssis-script-component-vs-derived-column/

Comment: when i'm ruuning this i'm getting  this Run time error : The UTC Offset of the local dateTime parameter does not match the offset argument.
Parameter name: offset

Comment: @mohan111 this is weird since i tested it on my machine and it works. I will search for that and get back to you

Comment: I will check n get back to you @hadi

Comment: It worked thanks for you support and guiding me on this