# How to convert DatePicker's DateTime to Realm's DateTimeOffset in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, type-conversion, realm

I have a class that is inherited from RealmObject with the Birthday property, which I enter with DatePicker. But Realm only works with DateTimeOffset. How can I elegantly convert all this?

XAML

```
<DatePicker MinimumDate="01/01/1400"
                        MaximumDate="11/14/2019"
                        Date="{Binding Author.Birthday}" />
```

Class Author

```
    public class Author : RealmObject
{
    //[PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PhotoPath { get; set; }
    [Ignored]
    public Image Photo { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? Birthday { get; set; }
    public IList<Book> Books { get; }
    public bool IsFavorite { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Using a value converter with the help of
   [this](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/)
2. Convert DateTime to DateTimeOffset with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933654/convert-utc-datetime-to-datetimeoffset)
3. And if you are using that picker to show data as well you need to implement ConvertBack method of value converter. Converting Offset to DateTime rather easy as returning : `offset.DateTime`

For in depth DateTimeOffset : [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-datetime-and-offset)